# LiveData never gets updated

Tags: android-room, android-livedata

In my App i insert a couple of "route" objects using room. directly after doing the insert the app shows a new screen where i need the data.

The Problem looks like the insert takes place after the new view is already created, i insert the data by using ViewModel-> Repository -> DAO

On the next screen i observe the Data

```
@Query("SELECT * from RouteEntity")
fun getRoutesAsLiveData(): LiveData<List<RouteEntity>>
```

How do i "sync" that the insert which seem to run after the new screen is already shown triggers the observed livedata ?

Comment: Could you please post your insert query function.

Answer (score 1):

As I can understand, you want to navigate to a new screen immediately after data insertion, and also want to observe the newly inserted data from the Database.

The insertion is an asynchronous operation and you may have to wait for the insertion acknowledgement callback to take the user to a new screen.

Unfortunately, LiveData doesn't support callback response for Insertion/Delete/Update operation.

As per google docs ([Source](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#return-types)), the LiveData support is N/A for One-shot write/read.
I recommend RxJava's Single wrapped with a Long object.

```
  @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
  fun insert(routeEntity: RouteEntity): Single<Long>
```

Where Long returns the rowId for the inserted item.
With this approach, you could take the user to a new screen when you get an onSuccess() response from Single.

Comment: using RX is not that option i was hoping for.

Comment: @Kitesurfer I understand you don't want to introduce Rx just for this use case. Could you please post the code you use for observing data changes on your new screen. If you observe the live-data in onCreateView(), data should get updated.